# Should I use SQL or NoSQL to store a very large number of unique strings or integers?

Tags: sql, nosql, redis

I want to store a very large number (1,000,000s) of **unique** strings or integers for quick reference (this string exists in db/store or not).

There is no complex data relationships, just an ever increasing plain list of strings( or integers or may be hash). And I want to query this list very frequently to see if a entity exists in this list or not. I do not want it to consume too many disk I/O cycles to too much of memory.

I have tried to compare NoSQL (mongo) and SQL (Postgres & MySQL) for my requirements. But still I am not sure about the definite answer.

Update: I want to keep this data persistent. So, in case of power outage or system reboot, I can resume the app.

Comment: You are describing a key value store - so why not use a key value store - like e.g. Redis

Comment: If it's only a few million, the cheapest and easiest option is probably an in-memory hash table in whatever language you're using, and a pack of multi-GB DIMMs. In the end you'll be using either disk I/O or memory to do it; there's no magic way to compare against a few million ints or whatever without having to access them all somehow.

Comment: @AD7six so what data-type do you suggest? A single key with list data-type, string data-type with my unique string as keys or some other?

Comment: @irfan Do you just want to check if a specific value exists?

Comment: @alexn yes this all, nothing more than that

Comment: @Irfan If you have duplicates, go for a hash. If you only have unique items, go for a set. Use SISMEMBER/HEXISTS to determine if a given value exists.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks for your suggestion. Is there any way to make this persistent? I mean what if system has to rebooted or power outage? Should I have multiple save points after some specific time?

Comment: @Irfan If you need persistence (which you didn't specify) then something like Redis is likely better than rolling your own. I was just pointing out that if you don't need persistence - say, if you can easily re-calculate the data on startup from some underlying data set - *then* a simple hash table or b-tree based set may be all you need.

Comment: Thanks @alexn and Craig. Redis SETS seems to be best for my case.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like you want a really fast and simple key/value storage which doesn't even have values. There are better choices for such a use-case than MongoDB. There is, for example, [MemcacheDB](http://memcachedb.org/), a persistence-enabled dropin replacement for memcached.